# Do mutex locks happen in the same order they are asked?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am currently trying to create a very simple thread pool using `std::thread`.
In order to maintain threads 'alive' after their given task is done, I associate a `std::mutex` with each one of them.

The principle is somewhat like this:

```
// Thread loop
while (1)
{
  m_oMutex->lock();
  m_oMutex->unlock();
  m_bAvailable = false;
  m_oTask();
  m_bAvailable = true;
}

// ThreadPool function which gives a task to a thread
void  runTask(boost::function<void ()> oTask)
{
  [...]
  m_oThreads[i]->setTask(oTask);
  m_oMutexes[i]->unlock(); // same mutex as thread's m_oMutex
  m_oMutexes[i]->lock();
}
```

To find the `i`, the `ThreadPool` searches for a thread object with `m_bAvailable` set to `true`. It unlocks the corresponding mutex so the `thread` can lock it and execute its task. The `thread` unlocks it immediately so the `ThreadPool` can lock it again so the `thread` is halted once its task is done.

But the question is, will locks be made in the order the threads ask them? In other words, if a `thread` does a lock on a `mutex`, then the `ThreadPool` unlocks it and locks it again, am I sure that the lock will be given to the `thread` first? If not, is there a way to ensure it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot guarantee that your thread loop will ever acquire the lock with your example as is.  Use a conditional variable to signal to the thread loop that it should awake and take the lock.  See `std::condition_variable::wait(...)`.
[condition-variable](/questions/tagged/condition-variable)

More on this topic in general can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_variable. If you were using the pthread library, the equivalent call would be `pthread_cond_wait` in your "Thread loop" and `pthread_cond_signal` in your runTask function.

Comment: Thanks. `condition_variable` seems to do the trick perfectly. One question though, I tried the example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait and I don't get why the first thread to create a `std::unique_lock` with `cv_m` as a parameter is blocked, as he is the first one to lock the mutex (in `unique_lock`s constructor).

Comment: In that example, the waits threads will probably all acquire the lock, then release it while they wait for the signal.  The order in which those threads acquire the locks in non-deterministic since they are running asynchronously.  Then, the order they are awakened from their "wait" calls is also undefined because of the nature of multi-threading.  One thing will be certain though, and that's that each of those threads will have an exclusive lock on the code via the mutex while they run "cerr << "..finished waiting...."