# Some of the threads in my program are not getting the CPU cycle

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-c++, cpu-usage, cpu-speed

I have a program in which I have created `160 threads`-- for working on data directed to them respectively  and 1 thread-- which holds the data in a map.

All the threads are been created while running the program.

**problem:**
 At times my some threads out of 160 threads are not been able to read the data from map in the data thread.

I tried reducing the `Mutex locks` but still the problem remains the same.

please help for the same.

Comment: [There's no fairness guarantee](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527621/is-stdmutex-fair).

Comment: What about 159 threads, or 59, or... 4? You've not provided *nearly* enough information to assist with your problem, so at-best all you'll get are wags.

Comment: 160 threads seems unreasonably many

Comment: Why do you want for the 160 threads to read the data?

Comment: i want 160 threads to read as well as do sm operations..there are different operations done by all the 160 threads.