# How do I lock multiple mutexes without deadlock and without potential infinite blocking?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to lock multiple mutexes without a deadlock while also making sure no threads block forever.  From what I understand, `std::scoped_lock()` calls `std::lock()` to acquire its locks--which is blocking.  I'm worried about the poor, unlucky thread that never catches a break and always fails to acquire all of the locks when multiple locks are needed amidst a *lot* of concurrent access.

I get that critical sections should be as small and fast as possible; one needs to get in and out as quickly as possible to avoid long blocking times.  But surely even locking *well-written* code and critical sections can stress the mutex resources given enough concurrent requests.

I looked at using `std::timed_mutex` with `std::scoped_lock()`, but `std::timed_mutex::lock()` blocks and doesn't make use of the mutex's timed capability (would require `std::timed_mutex::try_lock_for()` or `std::timed_mutex::try_lock_until()`, which as far as I know isn't used by `std::scoped_lock()`).

So is there a way to lock multiple mutexes and guarantee that no thread will block forever while waiting to lock the mutexes (even if that means it doesn't acquire any locks)?  Is there a non-blocking version of `std::scoped_lock()`?  Can you break a blocked `std::scoped_lock()` call?  Should I expect the scenario of a thread blocking forever to be so rare that it's an acceptable risk?  Am I thinking too hard?

Comment: scoped_lock is just lock and unlock. You can call try_lock and unlock, or try_lock_for and unlock, if you want.

Comment: If you need to lock multiple mutexes, ensure that you always lock them all in the same order, and make sure that as soon as a lock cannot be obtained that all the locks are released and try again.  Don't do any transaction processing until all the locks are obtained.  And if possible, do what you can to avoid it.

Comment: @user253751, what I'm reading into your comment is that the deadlock avoidance algorithm from std::lock() is nothing fancy.  I can simply try_lock_for() on each mutex in series until either I get all the locks or one of them times out (at which point I unlock everything and move on).  Is that about it?  Is the deadlock avoidance algorithm really that trivial under the hood?

Comment: @kpieckiel It could be that trivial. It might have a heuristic like trying to lock the hardest lock first. But I daresay it's probably just the trivial one. Go and look in the header file and find out how *your* compiler does it - I believe in you!

Comment: C++17 - Have a read of [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) _"... __deadlock-avoiding__ RAII wrapper for multiple mutexes..."_  _"...The class scoped_lock is a mutex wrapper that provides a convenient RAII-style mechanism for owning one or more mutexes for the duration of a scoped block...."_

Comment: @RichardCritten, have a read of my question that I posted above.  That function is blocking.  In theory, a thread could block forever waiting to lock multiple mutexes.  That's the crux of my question... how to **keep a thread from blocking indefinitely** when locking multiple mutexes.

Comment: @user253751, thanks.  Your and Eljay's responses are helpful and pretty much answer my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is std::mutex fair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527621/is-stdmutex-fair)

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if you find that your code needs to lock multiple mutexes at once, that's a code-smell.... see if you can redesign your program so that no thread ever needs to hold more than one mutex at a time (and if that's not possible, then try to at least minimize the number of mutexes any thread will need to hold at one time, and enforce a consistent order-of-acquisition in order to avoid deadlocks)

Comment: @RichardCritten, this is helpful information.  Thank you for linking that.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I agree that fewer mutexes is better--and I appreciate the admonition/reminder.  In my scenario, I'm self-learning about the concepts of data-oriented design, and when applying it to a multi-threaded program, two pieces of disparate data (i.e., accessed via differing indexes or something) might need to be transformed together.  I see no way around locking multiple mutexes other than a giant lock that locks everything.  A comment is too small for a code example or more in-depth description, and it's entirely possible I'm doing the DoD wrong.  I _am_ still learning DoD.

Comment: @kpieckiel another approach would be to make each data structure accessible only by a single thread, and then implement thread-safe message queues so that threads can communicate with each other.  Then if thread A needs to update a data structure that is only accessible by thread B, thread A can post a message to thread B's message queue, causing thread B to wake up, handle the message, and update the data structure on thread A's behalf.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, ooh!  I like that approach--definitely worth considering using such a "guard thread."  Thanks for that idea!